# cppyy crash with uint8_t arrays

Tags: python, c++, c, cppyy

With cppyy 2.3.1 and python3.8, I could do the following:

```
import cppyy
cppyy.cppdef(''' struct T { uint8_t t[10]; }; ''')
t = cppyy.gbl.T()
bytes(t.t)
```

With cppyy 2.4.0 and above, I get a sigsev:

> #8  signal handler called
> #9  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:384
> #10 0x000056085fd8d582 in memcpy (__len=2147483640, __src=, __dest=0x7f0f27d56030) at
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:34
> #11 PyBuffer_ToContiguous (buf=buf entry=0x7f0f27d56030, src=src entry=0x7ffc116933b0, len=2147483640, order=order entry=67 'C') at
> Objects/memoryobject.c:997
> #12 0x000056085fe188d9 in _PyBytes_FromBuffer (x=) at Objects/bytesobject.c:2689
> #13 0x000056085fd56279 in bytes_new_impl (errors=0x0, encoding=0x0, x=0x7f0fa7dba6b0, type=0x56086000bac0 <PyBytes_Type>) at
> Objects/bytesobject.c:2667
> #14 bytes_new (type=0x56086000bac0 <PyBytes_Type>, args=, kwargs=) at Objects/clinic/bytesobject.c.h:894
> #15 0x000056085fda0bd5 in type_call (type=type entry=0x56086000bac0 <PyBytes_Type>, args=args entry=0x7f0fa7df0c70, kwds=kwds entry=0x0)
> at Objects/typeobject.c:1100

When I simply want to print t.t[0] I get a random number above 255. Trying to set it has no effect.

I've tried by installing from pip and from sources, and with both python 3.8 and 3.11.

cppyy-2.4.0 changelog mentions something about uint8_t enums, that were previously treated as 1-character strings.

Interestingly enough, if I use "unsigned char" instead of "uint8_t", it works as expected; however I have plenty of uint8_t in my code, so it's not an option.

Can anyone confirms this behavior ?
If it's indeed a bug in cppyy, is there another way or a workaround to access the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case is now fixed in repo.

The problem when mapping `int8_t` or `uint8_t` is that these are supposed to behave as integer types, but the actual underlying C++ types are `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Whereas in C/C++ the difference between `char` and `int` types is minimal, Python's `str` and `int` are completely unrelated types. Iow., wherever they are used, the `int8_t` and `uint8_t` typedefs must *not* be resolved, while at the same time, it's not possible to distinguish between e.g. `int8_t` and `signed char` in C++ itself using overloads or RTTI. Bit of a conundrum.